# How to find Negative maximum and positive minimum in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, max, min

I have a column of type `number`. It has both positive and negative values. I need to get 4 values : Positive Maximum,Positive Minimum, Negative Maximum,Negative Minimum:

a)To get Positive Maximum : I can use [Check out the Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6aa70/4)

```
select max(cola) from test;
```

b)To get Negative Minimum: I can use [Check out the Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6aa70/4)

```
select min(cola) from test;
```

I have two question here:

1)Now i'm not sure how to get the other two values. Guide me to get that

2)Meanwhile while trying this i got another doubt. When i have some column of type `varchar2` and it has numbers as value. I'm performing the above operation in this column. Positive maximum is same as above. But Negative minimum is quiet weird. [Check Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6aa70/5) .Why there is no proper implicit conversion is taking place here. Somebody pls explain the reason behind this?

Comment: For question 1, use **CASE** expression. For question 2, use **TO_NUMBER** to first convert the string into number and then rest is same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question 1, you can easily use case to determine which values you do the min/max on. E.g.:

```
select max(case when cola >= 0 then cola end) max_positive,
       min(case when cola >= 0 then cola end) min_positive,
       max(case when cola < 0 then cola end) max_negative,
       min(case when cola < 0 then cola end) min_negative
from   test;
```

For question 2, when you do the min/max on something that's a varchar, you're going to be doing string comparisons, *NOT* number comparisons. You have to explicitly convert the values to numbers, since Oracle doesn't know that you expected an implicit conversion to take place. And you shouldn't really rely on implicit conversions anyway. E.g.:

```
select max(case when to_number(cola) >= 0 then to_number(cola) end) max_positive,
       min(case when to_number(cola) >= 0 then to_number(cola) end) min_positive,
       max(case when to_number(cola) < 0 then to_number(cola) end) max_negative,
       min(case when to_number(cola) < 0 then to_number(cola) end) min_negative
from   test1;
```

[Here's the SQLFiddle for both cases.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6aa70/9)

N.B. I've explicitly split out both negative and positive values (I stuck 0 in with the positive numbers; you'll have to decide how you want to treat rows with a value of 0!), just in case there were no negative numbers or no positive numbers.

Comment: I should add that you can run into issues if you've got both numbers and text stored in your varchar2 column, and you do a to_number() on it. But you'd never store data in a column with the wrong kind of datatype, right?! *{;-)

Comment: Yes, there won't be any text in that column :)

Comment: There certainly won't, if it's been defined as a NUMBER! *{;-)

Answer (score 1):

use case expressions within the aggregation functions.

e.g.

max(when cola < 0 then cola end) max_neg

min(cola) min_neg -- no need for case expression here

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6aa70/10)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
Create table test(COLA number);

Insert into test values(1);
Insert into test values(50);
Insert into test values(-65);
Insert into test values(25);
Insert into test values(-2);
Insert into test values(-8);
Insert into test values(5);
Insert into test values(-11);

Create table test1(COLA varchar2(10));

Insert into test1 values('1');
Insert into test1 values('50');
Insert into test1 values('-65');
Insert into test1 values('25');
Insert into test1 values('-2');
Insert into test1 values('-8');
Insert into test1 values('5');
Insert into test1 values('-11');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      max(case when cola < 0 then cola end) max_neg_cola
    , min(cola) 
    , min(case when cola > 0 then cola end) min_pos_cola
    , max(cola) 
from test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6aa70/10/0)**:

```
| MAX_NEG_COLA | MIN(COLA) | MIN_POS_COLA | MAX(COLA) |
|--------------|-----------|--------------|-----------|
|           -2 |       -65 |            1 |        50 |
```

Comment: q 2 (was it added?), as stated elsewhere, use TO_NUMBER()

Answer (score 1):

> 1)Now i'm not sure how to get the other two values.

Use **CASE** expression.

```
SQL> SELECT MAX(
  2    CASE
  3      WHEN cola >= 0
  4      THEN cola
  5    END) max_positive,
  6    MIN(
  7    CASE
  8      WHEN cola >= 0
  9      THEN cola
 10    END) min_positive,
 11    MAX(
 12    CASE
 13      WHEN cola < 0
 14      THEN cola
 15    END) max_negative,
 16    MIN(
 17    CASE
 18      WHEN cola < 0
 19      THEN cola
 20    END) min_negative
 21  FROM test;

MAX_POSITIVE MIN_POSITIVE MAX_NEGATIVE MIN_NEGATIVE
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
          50            1           -2          -65

SQL>
```

> 2)Meanwhile while trying this i got another doubt. When i have some column of type varchar2 and it has numbers as value. I'm performing the above operation in this column. Positive maximum is same as above. But Negative minimum is quiet weird.

You need to first convert the **STRING** into **NUMBER** and then use the same query. For less typing of to_number every time, you could use **WITH** clause.

**NOTE** You must only have numbers in this column, and no **alphanumeric**. Else, be sure to get **`ORA-01722: invalid number`** error.

```
SQL> WITH t AS
  2    ( SELECT to_number(cola) cola FROM test1
  3    )
  4  SELECT MAX(
  5    CASE
  6      WHEN cola >= 0
  7      THEN cola
  8    END) max_positive,
  9    MIN(
 10    CASE
 11      WHEN cola >= 0
 12      THEN cola
 13    END) min_positive,
 14    MAX(
 15    CASE
 16      WHEN cola < 0
 17      THEN cola
 18    END) max_negative,
 19    MIN(
 20    CASE
 21      WHEN cola < 0
 22      THEN cola
 23    END) min_negative
 24  FROM t;

MAX_POSITIVE MIN_POSITIVE MAX_NEGATIVE MIN_NEGATIVE
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
          50            1           -2          -65

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

To get positive minimum value try this..

```
select min(cola) from test where cola>0;
```

To get negative maximum value try this..

```
select max(cola) from test where cola<0;
```